# Django-autocomplete-light migrate from 2.3.3 to 3.1 select2 rendering

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, jquery-select2

In v. 2.3.3 I used to customize the results with a template like this in "navigation_autocomplete/autocomplete.html":

```
  {% for finded in results %}
  <tr >
    <td><a class="button"> {{ finded.name }}</a>   </td>
    <td>{{ finded.code  |default:" - " }} </td>

  {% empty %}
  <tr> Nothing found </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Now I understand that you use select2, but looking in select2.js I cannot understand where data are rendered.

https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/blob/0bb92035f2a146a829a9ed992d0000559c6d0d02/src/dal_select2/views.py

I get only the "text" that is returned by the unicode method of the searched model.
What am I missing to customize display of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAL do not handle client side anymore. You have to checkout [select2](https://select2.github.io/) documentation to template it, it is out of the scope of DAL 3.

I have never tried to template it, but on the homepage we can read

> Fits in with your theme.
>
> Fully skinnable, CSS built with Sass and an optional theme for Bootstrap 3.

So I guess you can.

Comment: thanks for explanation, this solved all problems: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design